# Как "парсить" фотогрфии или видео

Tags: android, kotlin, видео, камера, photo

Изучаю Flutter, хочу сделать что-то на подобие вот [этого](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.depADVANCE.Blink&hl=ru). В идеале было бы найти библиотеку которая может в реальном времни обрабатывать данные с камеры который мы можем задавать что и искать или что-то готовое. Но как говорится чудес не бывает...

Ткните носом как называется это направление где занимаются "парсингом" фото видео, для получения данных из камеры/видео/фото. Ссылки на ру ресурсы будет хорошо, нет же, и иномирянским буду рад.

P.S. Java, Kotlin, Dart (Flutter), с C++ оч. плохо, на крайняк тоже пойдёт, что бы вкурить как это всё работает.

Comment: Это не парсингом называется, а машинным зрением. копайте в сторону OpenCV, на андроиде более-менее работает

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview